# Beamer showing duplicated slides when hiding notes

Tags: beamer, overlays

The presentation often uses multiple note pages per frame (`\note<2>{text}`) resulting multiple slides.

Consider a frame with no overlay specification itself and is just duplicated to more than 1 slide because of overlay specification on the notes. Using the \setbeameroption{hide notes} will remove notes but the frame still has more than 1 slides which should not have. How I can remove duplicated slides?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{hide notes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 1
  \note<1>{information}
  \note<2>{more information}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know a way accomplish only 1 occurrence of each slide? Maybe by some option for beamer or the way the notes are setup.

Comment: Use `\note{>xour text>}` instead of `\note<1>` and `\note<2>`.

Comment: Using `\note{>your text>}` puts all notes in one note page and since they are long I'm not able to see all notes when creating the pdf with notes. I added a clarification regarding this in the original post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I seem to have missed that part in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The following MWE should give you the desired result of a single frame and two note pages:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 1
\end{frame}
  \note{information on the first note page}
  \note{more information on the second note page}

\end{document}
```

In comparison to your code, I have moved the `\note` commands outside of the `frame` environment. However, please keep in mind the following from the `beamer` manual (See "19.1  Specifying Note Contents", page 204):

> To add a note to a slide or a frame, use the `\note` command. This command
>   can be used both inside and outside frames, but it has quite different
>   behaviors then: Inside frames, `\note` commands accumulate and append a
>   single note page after the current slide; outside frames
>   each `\note`directly inserts a single note page with the given parameter
>   as contents. Using the `\note` command inside frames is usually preferably
>   over using them outside, since only commands issued inside frames
>   profit from the class option `onlyslideswithnotes`, see below. Inside a
>   frame, the effect of `\note⟨text⟩` is the following: When you use it
>   somewhere inside the frame on a specific slide, a note page is created
>   after the slide, containing the `⟨text⟩`.  Since you can add an
>   overlay specification to the `\note` command, you can specify after which
>   slide the note should be shown. If you use multiple `\note` commands on one
>   slide, they “accumulate” and are all shown on the same note. [...]
>   Outside frames, the command `\note` creates a single note page. It is
>   “independent” of any usage of the `\note` commands inside the previous
>   frame. If you say `\note` inside a frame and `\note` right after
>   it, two notepages are created.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your example does what I wanted. Unfortunately it doesn't work in the document I'm working on. The document defines the frames as a new environment, which might be an issue. Can't reproduce it with a minimal example yet though. The code I have does something like this:
`\newenvironment{decoratedFrame}{
 \begin{frame}
  Content that gets repeated
 \end{frame}
}`
And then uses the decoratedFrame. I will try to come up with an minimal example...